# Injecting the Ninject NamedScope-defining object into its own scope

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, ninject

I have an object that is bound in Ninject like this:

```
Bind<IScopeRoot>().To<ScopeRoot>()
    .DefinesNamedScope("DemoScope");
```

There are multiple objects in that scope:

```
Bind<IRootedObject>().To<RootedObject>()
   .InNamedScape("DemoScope");
```

The problem I run into is that injecting IScopeRoot into a RootedObject will create a new ScopeRoot instance (the root of a new DemoScope) instead of injecting the scope-defining object.

A work-around I used was to create an artificial root object that is nothing but a container for the actual root object, but I feel that is ugly and that it messes up my architecture.

Is there a nice way to inject the scope-defining object into its own scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally Ninject is putting a `NamedScopeParameter` on the context of the `ScopeRoot`(=> Binding `.DefinesNamedScope`).

*Warning*: I haven't actually compiled any of the following code, but conceptually it should work. Feel free to fix any mistakes i made.

We had the same problem and we used to implement an `IScopeRootFactory` like that:

```
internal class ScopeRootFactory : IScopeRootFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public ScopeRootFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IScopeRoot CreateScopeRoot()
    {
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get<IScopeRoot>(new NamedScopeParameter("ScopeName");
    }
}
```

Your bindings will then look like:

```
Bind<IScopeRootFactory>().To<ScopeRootFactory>();
Bind<IScopeRoot>().To<ScopeRoot>()
    .InNamedScope("ScopeName");
Bind<IRootedObject>().To<RootedObject>()
     .InNamedScope("ScopeName");
```

### Alternative: ToMethod binding

```
 Bind<ScopeRoot>.ToSelf()
     .InNamedScope("ScopeName");
 Bind<IScopeRoot>()
     .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ScopeRoot>(
           new NamedScopeParameter("ScopeName");
Bind<IRootedObject>().To<RootedObject>()
     .InNamedScope("ScopeName");
```

Maybe there's also some more elegant way to achieve this.